# UWP Cannot resolve assembly System.Windows.Forms

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal

I'm working on a UWP project in which I'm trying to add a third-party library. I added the library and everything seemed to work fine until I cleaned and rebuild the solution? Now I'm getting:

```
Cannot resolve Assembly or Windows Metadata file 'Type universe cannot resolve assembly: System.Windows.Forms ...  Project.csproj
```

and

```
Could not copy the file "obj\x86\Debug\FavoriteControl\Favorite.xbf" because it was not found.
```

I definitely know that the errors are from the library. The library was added through Reference and some header were added inside the project.

Comment: Targeting Winforms is only possible in a project that targets .NETFramework or .NETCore3.1, not in UWP.  You can't use this library.

Comment: Isn't there any other option, to use a bridge desktop? I've seen some references online.

Answer (score 0):

Currently it is not possible. NET Core is still developing gradually that's the reason it does not work in .NET Core and work in .NET Framework.

Comment: Do you have any idea if there is any bridge to desktop to make it work?

Comment: I think you need to report this issue to msdn